# Error using \ifdefined\HCode with TeX4ht, but it works in LuaTeX

Tags: align, conditionals, tex4ht, breqn

I now use the `breqn` package in LuaTeX mode only. Not in TeX4ht mode since it does not work there and is not needed.  So I load breqn only when not in TeX4ht mode and use `\ifdefined\HCode` to make sure it is used only when compiling to PDF and not HTML.

I found some issue where TeX4ht still sees `{dmath*}` and `dgroup` which are commands from `breqn`, even though I made sure by using `\ifdefined\HCode` these only can be seen when compiling to PDF.

Compiling to PDF doesn't show any error at all. But compiling to HTML gives an error.

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\ifdefined\HCode %only load breaqn when not in TeX4ht mode
\else
\usepackage{breqn}
\fi

\begin{document}
\ifdefined\HCode
\begin{align*}
\else
\begin{dgroup*}
\fi

\ifdefined\HCode
   A &= B
\else
\begin{dmath*}
   A = B
\end{dmath*}     %error is around here
\fi

\ifdefined\HCode
\end{align*}
\else
\end{dgroup*}
\fi
\end{document}
```

Compiling using `lualatex foo2.tex` doesn't give any error and correct output.

But

```
make4ht -ulm default -a debug foo2.tex "mathjax,htm"
```

gives

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html5.4ht)) (./foo2.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)

! LaTeX Error: Environment dgroup* undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.31 \end{dmath*}
```

I had to do it this way. It is a long story, but my question is: Why does the above work correctly with LuaTeX, but not with TeX4ht? Am I doing something wrong? If yes, then how come LuaTeX is happy with it, but not TeX4ht?  Is there a way to make tex4ht compile the above?

I am using [TeX Live](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX_Live) (TL) 2021, and it was updated about two weeks ago. On Linux.

**Update oct 25, 2021**

I found an issue with proposed solution. It does not work with multiple `dmath*` inside `dgroup*`. It only works with one `dmath*` inside `dgroup*`. But if I have one `dmath*`, I really do not need `dgroup*`.

Since hard to show all this in a comment to the answer, I show it here.

Here is MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}    
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}    

\begin{dgroup*}
\begin{dmath*}
   A = B
\end{dmath*}      
\begin{dmath*}
   C = D
\end{dmath*}    
\end{dgroup*}
\end{document}
```

Using same .cfg file shown in the answer, and compiled using

```
make4ht -ulm default -a debug -c ./new.cfg test_breqn.tex "mathjax,htm"
```

gives this HTML

[image]

The second `dmath*` needs to be on new line. The HTML is

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang='en-US' xml:lang='en-US'> 
<head> <title></title> 
<meta charset='utf-8' /> 
<meta content='TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)' name='generator' /> 
<meta content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1' name='viewport' /> 
<link href='test_breqn.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' /> 
<meta content='test_breqn.tex' name='src' /> 
<script>window.MathJax = { tex: { tags: "ams", environments: { "dgroup*": ["", ""], "dmath*": ["", ""], }  } }</script> 
 <script async='async' id='MathJax-script' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml-full.js' type='text/javascript'></script>  
</head><body>
<!-- l. 13 --><p class='noindent'>\begin {dgroup*} \begin {dmath*} A = B \end {dmath*} \begin {dmath*} C = D \end {dmath*} \end {dgroup*}
</p>   
 
</body> 
</html>
```

This is the PDF version:

[image]

I hope there is a way around this.

Comment: `\ifdefined\HCode
\begin{align*}
\else
\begin{dgroup*}
\fi` can't really work, you need the condition around the entire environment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit:

You can also use `make4ht` filters to edit the math content in the HTML file to get something that MathJax supports. For example, the following build file converts `dgroup*` environment to `align*`, and it also changes the math content to suitable form:

```lua
local filter = require "make4ht-filter"

local function process_options(options)
  -- convert [number={foo}] to \tag{foo}
  local number = options:match("number%s*=%s*{?(%w+)")
  if number then
    return "\\tag{" .. number .. "}"
  end
  return ""
end


local function escape_equal(str)
  -- there can be multiple equal characters in the string. we should put the & character
  -- just before the one which is not inside any group
  -- escape nested equal signs
  str = str:gsub("({[^{^}]+)=([^{^}]+})", "%1:EQUAL:%2")
  -- replace remaining =
  str = str:gsub("=", "&=")
  -- return escaped =
  str = str:gsub(":EQUAL:", "=")
  return str
end

local function make_align(dgroup)
  -- change breqn environment contents to align*
  -- change = to &=
  local dgroup = escape_equal(dgroup)
  -- return the fixed text in align* environment
  return "\\begin{align*}" ..  dgroup .. "\\end{align*}"
end

local function process_dgroup(s, env_name)
  return s:gsub("\\begin%s*{" .. env_name .. "}(.-)\\end%s*{" .. env_name .. "}",
  function(dgroup)
    -- remove environemnts
    -- change dmath[...,number={label}] to \tag{label}
    dgroup = dgroup:gsub("\\begin%s*{dmath}%s*(%b[])", process_options)
    -- remove all other environemnts
    dgroup = dgroup:gsub("\\begin%s*{.-}","")
    dgroup = dgroup:gsub("\\end%s*{.-}", "\\\\")
    return make_align(dgroup)
  end)
end

-- process remaining dmath environments
local function process_dmath(s, env_name)
  return s:gsub("\\begin%s*{" .. env_name .. "}(.-)\\end%s*{" .. env_name .. "}",
  function(dmath)
    -- options can be still here
    local dmath = dmath:gsub("^%s*(%b[])", process_options)
    return make_align(dmath)
  end)
end

local process = filter {
  -- find all dgroup* environments and convert them to align*
  function(s)
    local s = process_dgroup(s,"dgroup%*")
    s = process_dgroup(s, "dgroup")
    -- process remaining dmath environments in the document
    s = process_dmath(s, "dmath%*")
    s = process_dmath(s, "dmath")
    return s
  end
}


-- install filter to match HTML files
Make:match("html?$", process)
```

It produces a following HTML code:

```html
<p class='noindent'>test 1, OK
</p><!-- l. 15 --><p class='indent'>   \begin{align*}  A &amp;= B \\  C &amp;= D \\ \end{align*}
</p><!-- l. 17 --><p class='indent'>   test 2 FAIL
</p><!-- l. 26 --><p class='indent'>   \begin{align*}  A &amp;= B \\ \tag{1} C &amp;= D \\ \end{align*}
</p><!-- l. 29 --><p class='indent'>   test 3 OK
</p><!-- l. 33 --><p class='indent'>   \begin{align*} A &amp;= B \end{align*}
</p><!-- l. 35 --><p class='indent'>   test 4 FAIL
</p><!-- l. 39 --><p class='indent'>   \begin{align*}\tag{1} A &amp;= B \end{align*}
</p><!-- l. 41 --><p class='indent'>   test 5 OK
</p><!-- l. 45 --><p class='indent'>   \begin{align*} A &amp;= B \end{align*}
</p>
```

Which is displayed by MathJax like this:

[image]

Original answer:

Alternatively, you can add support for your math environments to MathJax, using this config file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml} 
\Configure{MathJaxConfig}{{ 
    tex: { 
      tags: "ams", 
      \detokenize{% 
      environments: {
        "dgroup*": ["", ""],
        "dmath*": ["", ""],
      } 
  } 
} 
}} 
\VerbMath{dgroup*}
\begin{document} 
\EndPreamble
```

The `\VerbMath{dgroup*}` command ensures that TeX4ht passes the whole content of the `dgroup*` environment to the HTML file. You then need to configure MathJax to support both `dgroup*` and `dmath*` environments. This is thanks to:

```
  environments: {
    "dgroup*": ["", ""],
    "dmath*": ["", ""],
  }
```

I've found that you don't need to provide any other code, MathJax just switches to the display math mode and prints the content.

Your TeX file can be then simplified:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}    
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}    
\begin{dgroup*}
\begin{dmath*}
   A = B
\end{dmath*}     %error is around here           
\end{dgroup*}
\end{document}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Comment: @Nasser should give you the tick:-)

Comment: Thanks! This is much easier so I do not have to duplicate code. I will test it more on my main file.

Comment: @Nasser yes, it is easier. you should try to avoid the `\ifdefined\HCode` in your documents, try to add support for unsupported commands instead :)

Comment: hi Michal. I found a problem. Please see updated answer. I hope there is a magic code you have that can fix this, otherwise, it will not really work.  I still need to test `dmath` and `dgroup` with `[number=label]` which give labels to equations in breqn. But one thing at a time :)

Comment: @Nasser you can post-process the HTML file using `make4ht` filters and fix some things here. I've updated my answer to show this.

Comment: Thank you Michal. I Will spend rest of the day testing this setup see how it works.  I never used the `-e` option with make4ht before with lua file, only with .mk4 file. Will let you know. cheers.

Comment: I hope it works. It should be easy to adapt this code for more environments.

Answer (score 5):

If `\Hcode` is defined then `\begin{align*}` will be executed and as a first action this will grab all the code up to `\end{align*}`. This body is executed multiple times, once with a measuring pass and then a main typesetting pass. The body collected will be

```
\else
\begin{dgroup*}
\fi

\ifdefined\HCode
   A &= B
\else
\begin{dmath*}
   A = B
\end{dmath*}     %error is around here           
\fi

\ifdefined\HCode
```

and the `if` conditionals will be unmatched.  You need the conditional to be around the entire environment.