# Tex4ht generates invalid math in mathjax mode when using dmath

Tags: tex4ht, mathjax, breqn

The following MWE generates invalid math in HTML using mathjax mode. This only happens when using `dmath*`. I am using the solution from [Error using \ifdefined\HCode with TeX4ht, but it works in LuaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/620104/error-using-ifdefined-hcode-with-tex4ht-but-it-works-in-luatex)  and give below all code needed to reproduce this problem using a MWE.

The Latex come from Mathematica conversion:

```
 sol = DSolve[y'[x] == 2*y[x]/x + x^3/y[x] + x*Tan[y[x]/x^2], y[x], x]
 TeXForm[sol]
```

Gives

```
\text{Solve}\left[3 \log (x)-\log \left(y(x) \sin \left(\frac{y(x)}{x^2}\right)+x^2 \cos \left(\frac{y(x)}{x^2}\right)\right)=c_1,y(x)\right]
```

`tex4ht` converts the above Latex OK when putting the above inside an equation. But when the Latex is inside `dmath` it given HTML which is not valid. (can't be rendered by mathjax)

Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}    

\[
\text{Solve}\left[3 \log (x)-\log \left(y(x) \sin \left(\frac{y(x)}{x^2}\right)+x^2 \cos \left(\frac{y(x)}{x^2}\right)\right)=c_1,y(x)\right]
\]

\begin{dmath*}
\text{Solve}\left[3 \log (x)-\log \left(y(x) \sin \left(\frac{y(x)}{x^2}\right)+x^2 \cos \left(\frac{y(x)}{x^2}\right)\right)=c_1,y(x)\right]
\end{dmath*}

\end{document}
```

Compiled using

```
 make4ht  -ulm default -c ./new.cfg -e ./filter.lua -a debug index.tex "mathjax,htm"
```

Gives

[image]

Here is the raw HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang='en-US' xml:lang='en-US'> 
<head> <title></title> 
<meta charset='utf-8' /> 
<meta content='TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)' name='generator' /> 
<meta content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1' name='viewport' /> 
<link href='index.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' /> 
<meta content='index.tex' name='src' /> 
<script>window.MathJax = { tex: { tags: "ams", maxBuffer: 40*1024, packages: {'[+]': ['textmacros']}, environments: { "dgroup*": ["", ""], "dmath*": ["", ""], "dgroup": ["", ""], "dmath": ["", ""] }, macros: { sp: "^", sb: "_", noalign: ["\#1", 1], }, packages: {'[+]': ['noerrors','textmacros']} }, loader: { load: ['[tex]/noerrors','[tex]/textmacros'] } }; </script> 
 <script async='async' id='MathJax-script' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml-full.js' type='text/javascript'></script>  
</head><body>
<!-- l. 11 --><p class='noindent'>\begin {align*}  \text {Solve}\left [3 \log (x)-\log \left (y(x) \sin \left (\frac {y(x)}{x^2}\right )+x^2 \cos \left (\frac {y(x)}{x^2}\right )\right )=c_1,y(x)\right ]  \end {align*}

</p><!-- l. 15 --><p class='noindent'>\begin{align*}  \text {Solve}\left [3 \log (x)-\log \left (y(x) \sin \left (\frac {y(x)}{x^2}\right )+x^2 \cos \left (\frac {y(x)}{x^2}\right )\right )&amp;=c_1,y(x)\right ]  \end{align*}
</p>   
 
</body> 
</html>
```

By trial and error, I found the problem goes away when removing `\left[` and `right]` !  I also noticed that tex4ht generates `&amp;` in the raw HTML above near the end of the line, when `\left[` and `right]` are present which might be the cause of the problem (*need to check*).

**YES. Confirmed**  When removing `&amp;` from the HTML generated, now mathjax renders it OK.

[image]

This happens only when using `dmath*` environment and not normal equation `\[ \]` or normal `align*` environment.

### Appendix

Here are the files `new.cfg` and `filter.lua` used in the above command

**new.cfg**

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
%V3.0
\Configure{MathJaxConfig}{{
  tex: {
    tags: "ams",
    maxBuffer: 40*1024,
    packages: {'[+]': ['textmacros']},
    \detokenize{%
      environments: {
        "dgroup*": ["", ""],
        "dmath*": ["", ""],
        "dgroup": ["", ""],
        "dmath": ["", ""]
      }},
    \unexpanded{%
    macros: {
        sp: "^",
        sb: "_",
      noalign: ["\#1", 1],
    }},
    packages: {'[+]': ['noerrors','textmacros']}
  },
  loader: {
    load: ['[tex]/noerrors','[tex]/textmacros']
  }
};
}

%Thanks to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/620104/error-using-ifdefined-hcode-with-tex4ht-but-it-works-in-luatex/620138?noredirect=1#comment1548405_620138
%IMPORTANT. Need also .config folder in my HOME folder for this to work.
\VerbMath{dgroup*}
\VerbMath{dmath*}
\VerbMath{dgroup}
\VerbMath{dmath}


\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

**filter.lua**

```
local filter = require "make4ht-filter"

local function process_options(options)
  -- convert [number={foo}] to \tag{foo}
  local number = options:match("number%s*=%s*{?(%w+)")
  if number then
    return "\\tag{" .. number .. "}"
  end
  return ""
end


local function escape_equal(str)
  -- there can be multiple equal characters in the string. we should put the & character
  -- just before the one which is not inside any group
  -- escape nested equal signs
  str = str:gsub("({[^{^}]+)=([^{^}]+})", "%1:EQUAL:%2")
  -- replace remaining =
  str = str:gsub("=", "&=")
  -- return escaped =
  str = str:gsub(":EQUAL:", "=")
  return str
end

local function make_align(dgroup)
  -- change breqn environment contents to align*
  -- change = to &=
  local dgroup = escape_equal(dgroup)
  -- return the fixed text in align* environment
  return "\\begin{align*}" ..  dgroup .. "\\end{align*}"
end

local function process_dgroup(s, env_name)
  return s:gsub("\\begin%s*{" .. env_name .. "}(.-)\\end%s*{" .. env_name .. "}",
  function(dgroup)
    -- remove environemnts
    -- change dmath[...,number={label}] to \tag{label}
    dgroup = dgroup:gsub("\\begin%s*{dmath}%s*(%b[])", process_options)
    -- remove all other environemnts
    dgroup = dgroup:gsub("\\begin%s*{.-}","")
    dgroup = dgroup:gsub("\\end%s*{.-}", "\\\\")
    return make_align(dgroup)
  end)
end

-- process remaining dmath environments
local function process_dmath(s, env_name)
  return s:gsub("\\begin%s*{" .. env_name .. "}(.-)\\end%s*{" .. env_name .. "}",
  function(dmath)
    -- options can be still here
    local dmath = dmath:gsub("^%s*(%b[])", process_options)
    return make_align(dmath)
  end)
end

local process = filter {
  -- find all dgroup* environments and convert them to align*
  function(s)
    local s = process_dgroup(s,"dgroup%*")
    s = process_dgroup(s, "dgroup")
    -- process remaining dmath environments in the document
    s = process_dmath(s, "dmath%*")
    s = process_dmath(s, "dmath")
    return s
  end
}


-- install filter to match HTML files
Make:match("html?$", process)
```

Using TL 2021 on Linux ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the issue is that the `&=` is inside `\left[` ... `\right]`. It seems like a MathJax issue. The `&` character should be used inside `align*` for correct alignment of multiline equations, but it doesn't work in this case. Maybe we can just omit it.

Try this version of the `build` file:

```lua
local filter = require "make4ht-filter"

local function process_options(options)
  -- convert [number={foo}] to \tag{foo}
  local number = options:match("number%s*=%s*{?(%w+)")
  if number then
    return "\\tag{" .. number .. "}"
  end
  return ""
end


local function escape_equal(str)
  -- there can be multiple equal characters in the string. we should put the & character
  -- just before the one which is not inside any group
  -- escape nested equal signs
  str = str:gsub("({[^{^}]+)=([^{^}]+})", "%1:EQUAL:%2")
  -- replace remaining =
  str = str:gsub("=", "& =")
  -- return escaped =
  str = str:gsub(":EQUAL:", "=")
  return str
end

local function make_align(dgroup, new_env)
  -- change breqn environment contents to align*
  -- change = to &=
  
  local dgroup = dgroup
  if not new_env then
    dgroup = escape_equal(dgroup) --  <- we don't do this anymore, it leads only to problems
  end
  local new_env = new_env or  "\\begin{align*}\n%s\n\\end{align*}"
  -- return the fixed text in align* environment
  -- return "\\begin{".. new_env .."}" ..  dgroup .. "\\end{" .. new_env .. "}"
  return string.format(new_env, dgroup)
end

local function process_dgroup(s, env_name)
  return s:gsub("\\begin%s*{" .. env_name .. "}(.-)\\end%s*{" .. env_name .. "}",
  function(dgroup)
    -- remove environemnts
    -- change dmath[...,number={label}] to \tag{label}
    dgroup = dgroup:gsub("\\begin%s*{dmath}%s*(%b[])", process_options)
    -- remove all other environemnts
    dgroup = dgroup:gsub("\\begin%s*{.-}","")
    dgroup = dgroup:gsub("\\end%s*{.-}", "\\\\")
    return make_align(dgroup)
  end)
end

-- process remaining dmath environments
local function process_dmath(s, env_name, new_env)
  return s:gsub("\\begin%s*{" .. env_name .. "}(.-)\\end%s*{" .. env_name .. "}",
  function(dmath)
    -- options can be still here
    local dmath = dmath:gsub("^%s*(%b[])", process_options)
    return make_align(dmath, new_env)
  end)
end


local process = filter {
  -- find all dgroup* environments and convert them to align*
  function(s)
    local s = process_dgroup(s,"dgroup%*")
    s = process_dgroup(s, "dgroup")
    -- process remaining dmath environments in the document
    s = process_dmath(s, "dmath%*", "\\[\n%s\n\\]")
    s = process_dmath(s, "dmath", "\\begin{equation}\n%s\n \\end{equation}")
    return s
  end
}

-- install filter to match HTML files
Make:match("html?$", process)
```

The change is that it now don't convert everything to the `align*` environment, but it follows `breqn`, so `dmath` -> `equation`, and `dmath*` -> `\[ ... \]`. It also doesn't escape the equals sign.

This is a resulting HTML:

```html
<!-- l. 10 --><p class='noindent'>\[ \text {Solve}\left [3 \log (x)-\log \left (y(x) \sin \left (\frac {y(x)}{x^2}\right )+x^2 \cos \left (\frac {y(x)}{x^2}\right )\right )=c_1,y(x)\right ] \]
</p><!-- l. 14 --><p class='indent'>   \[
  \text {Solve}\left [3 \log (x)-\log \left (y(x) \sin \left (\frac {y(x)}{x^2}\right )+x^2 \cos \left (\frac {y(x)}{x^2}\right )\right )=c_1,y(x)\right ]  
\]
</p>
```

And rendered by MathJax:

[image]

Comment: It is not a MathJax issue; the LaTeX is incorrect.  An ampersand in that position leads to an error in LaTeX as well, since you can't use an ampersand for the outer align environment inside the `\left...\right`, as the `\left...\right` act as grouping braces, and the ampersand can't be inside a group.  So it seems to be the `tex4ht` conversion that is at fault.

Comment: Thanks Michale. I have to test your new version on my large file which has thousands of cases to see if it works OK and does not break anything. I will let you know. On the ampersand issue. Mathematica does not generate one from its Latex conversion as can be seen from above. That ampersand seems to have come from TeX4ht itself somehow.

Comment: @DavideCervone thanks for clarification. I've added amperesands in the Lua filter, because I thought that they are useful for the alignment. But they do more harm than good, so I removed them from the updated filter in my answer.

Comment: Hello Michal. I still get same issue with your new version above. Is it possible may be you used different version than the one you posted? But I did a `diff` and I see changes made indeed. Could you please be kind enough and look again. I put this [problem_april_6_2022.zip](https://12000.org/tmp/april_6_2022/problem_april_6_2022.zip) file which has the tex file and the above lua file and the .cfg and used the same command which is `make4ht  -ulm default -c ./new.cfg -e ./filter.lua -a debug index.tex "mathjax,htm"` but the generated HTML still shows the same thing as before.  using TL 2021

Comment: @Nasser yes, amperesands were added by the filter. It now doesn't add them, and it also uses different environments than `align*`.

Comment: May be make4ht uses the lua filter in my `HOME/.config/make4ht/config.lua` by default even though I explicitly said `-e ./filter.lua` in the command? So it ignored the local lua filter? I will check on this now...

Comment: @Nasser it should use both config files

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that was it!  It was still using the lua filter in my HOME. I removed it and now got correct result as you show. I thought by adding `-e filter.lua` this will override the default one. I need to add this to my notes.  I think it will be better that if a user did `-e` then only this filter is used and not the one in the default HOME/.config folder. But this is not big issue now.

Comment: hi Michal. juts a small question. This version prints now on the screen the HTML header each time I compile a latex file. Before it did not do that. I assume there is a print statement doing this somewhere but did not see it. Here is screen shot. it comes right after the line `[INFO]    make4ht-lib: parse_lg process file: index.htm`  is possible to remove this as too much to print each time on the terminal screen. Thanks. ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WU1BG.png)

Comment: @Nasser it is actually a feature that both build file and config file are used.

Comment: @Nasser the printing of the code was for debuggging, I've removed it from the updated answer.

Comment: Hello Michal. I found new problem. for dgroup, your filter for some reason is not generating the amper `&` sign when converting to align. So all alignments are off when rendered in mathjax.  Would you like me to make new question on this, or just send you email via tex4ht mailing list? I've put zip file with example. Please see [this zip](https://12000.org/tmp/sept_4_2023/DMATH_problem_sept_4_2023.zip). The command I used is `make4ht  -ulm default -c ./my.cfg -e ./filter.lua -a debug main.tex "mathjax,htm,nostyle"`  I do not know why I did not notice this before. Thanks.

Comment: zip file contains the .cfg and your filter file (.lua) (same as you show above). So everything you need is inside the zip file. I tried this in TL 2022 and TL 2023 with same output.

Comment: @Nasser it would be best to make a new question. but I am a bit overwhelmed right now, I have about 10 reports that need to be processed, so it can take a time.

Comment: OK, will do that later. But could please at least just try the command I showed on the file? I wanted to see if it is nothing to do with my set up. It should not take you more than few minutes for this I hope as everything is in the zip file. If you are able to reproduce it, then I know it is nothing messed up on my PC. Thank you and good luck with your reports!

Comment: @Nasser I can see in the build file that in some version it escaped equal sign, but then it stopped because of some issues that it caused. But maybe I will be able to fix that.

Comment: Thanks you Michal for taking the time to look into it.

Comment: @Nasser I think it works now, at least for your example. try the updated code from this answer.

Comment: Hello @michal.h21 . I downloaded your new filter code from your updated answer now. I called it `new_filter.lua` and then issued the command `make4ht  -ulm default -c ./my.cfg -e ./new_filter.lua -a debug main.tex "mathjax,htm"`  but I am getting the same exact output as before.   no `&` shows in the generated align code. I've put the new zip file [here](https://12000.org/tmp/sept_4_2023/DMATH_problem_sept_5_2023.zip)  Is this the only change you made? Strange why it worked for you but not me. Here is screen shot also. ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QMPa.png)

Comment: Fixed!   I found the problem. I needed to delete also the OLD config.lua sitting in my `$HOME/.config/make4ht/config.lua` !!  It looks like make4ht is reading that automatically even though I have indicated `-e new_filter.lua` on the command line. This is really very confusing. But once I deleted the old .lua from my `$HOME/.config` folder, now it worked. Thank you.  screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsLBE.png)  I got bitten by this before.

Comment: @Nasser the `config.lua` is loaded automatically. I guess it contains a different version of this build file? I think we discussed it not a long time ago.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant that I got bitten by this before. I downloaded your changes into new_filter.lua and used `-e new_filter.lua`. The old config.lua was still  sitting in `$HOME/.config/make4ht/config.lua` folder and that was also read over writing what is being loaded by `-e`.  Once I realized this, I also updated the file in the config folder and now it works.  Having a hidden file being loaded automatically is really confusing. But this is not the right place to discuss it now.  Thanks again for the updated fix !