# How to use dmath with tex4ht without using mathjax? TL 2022

Tags: tex4ht, breqn

I am using the solution given in [tex4ht-generates-invalid-math-in-mathjax-mode-when-using-dmath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/639812/tex4ht-generates-invalid-math-in-mathjax-mode-when-using-dmath) which allows one to use `breqn` package in tex4ht which is very useful.

I am now trying to use the above, but without using `mathjax` in order to do timing on slow compilation I have to see if using `mathjax` is the cause. So I need to compile the document not in mathjax mode.

I did not know that one has to use `mathjax` for the above filter to work?

For some reason, I keep getting, in a new installed TL 2022, this error when I use `dmath` now.

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html5.4ht)) (./index.aux
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=50000].
<everymath> \check@mathfonts
                 \the \everymath
l.7 \begin{dmath*}

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, bad output DVI file produced!
No pages of output.
```

Below, I show everything needed to reproduce it, also I put a zip file with all the files needed and generated.

I must be doing something wrong.  I spend 3 hrs trying everything possible, but keep getting this error. If I do not use `dmath`, ofcourse it compiles OK.  Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}%ext
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}      

\begin{dmath*}
y(x) = x^{2}+x +3
\end{dmath*}
\end{document}
```

Now

```
>which make4ht
/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/make4ht
>make4ht --version
make4ht version v0.3l
>which dvilualatex
/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/dvilualatex
>dvilualatex --version
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.15.0 (TeX Live 2022)
Development id: 7509
```

Then did

```
 make4ht  -ulm default -a debug -e filter.lua   index.tex "htm"
```

Notice, I am not using `mathjax` option. Not using `.cfg` either. Only the filter, which is the exact one from the above answer thanks to Michal.h2. Here is the result

```
>make4ht  -ulm default -a debug -e filter.lua   index.tex "htm"
[INFO]    mkparams: Output dir:
[INFO]    mkparams: Compiler: dvilualatex
[INFO]    mkparams: Latex options: -jobname='index'
[INFO]    mkparams: tex4ht.sty: xhtml,htm,charset=utf-8
[INFO]    mkparams: tex4ht:  -cmozhtf -utf8
[INFO]    mkparams: build_file: filter.lua
[INFO]    mkparams: Output format: html5
[STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion started
[STATUS]  make4ht: Input file: index.tex
[INFO]    mkutils: Load extension       common_domfilters
[INFO]    mkutils: Using build file     filter.lua
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: setting param correct_exit
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: setting param correct_exit
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: setting param correct_exit
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: setting param ext
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: Adding:  ext     dvi
[INFO]    htlatex: LaTeX call: dvilualatex --interaction=errorstopmode -jobname='index'   '\makeatletter\def\HCode{\futurelet\HCode\HChar}\def\HChar{\ifx"\HCode\def\HCode"##1"{\Link##1}\expandafter\HCode\else\expandafter\Link\fi}\def\Link#1.a.b.c.{\AddToHook{class/before}{\RequirePackage[#1,html]{tex4ht}}\let\HCode\documentstyle\def\documentstyle{\let\documentstyle\HCode\expandafter\def\csname tex4ht\endcsname{#1,html}\def\HCode####1{\documentstyle[tex4ht,}\@ifnextchar[{\HCode}{\documentstyle[tex4ht]}}}\makeatother\HCode xhtml,htm,charset=utf-8,html5.a.b.c.\input "\detokenize{index.tex}"'
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.15.0 (TeX Live 2022)
 restricted system commands enabled.
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-04-20> (./index.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/tex4ht.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
....
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html5.4ht)) (./index.aux
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=50000].
<everymath> \check@mathfonts
                 \the \everymath
l.7 \begin{dmath*}

 335479 words of node memory still in use:
   16 hlist, 2 vlist, 2 rule, 4 local_par, 3 dir, 33330 math, 16 glue, 4 kern,
7 penalty, 3 glyph, 16852 attribute, 72 glue_spec, 16852 attribute_list, 3 temp
, 16665 if_stack, 2 write, 200 special nodes
   avail lists: 1:3,3:2,4:1,5:4,8:4
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, bad output DVI file produced!
No pages of output.
Transcript written on index.log.
[FATAL]   make4ht-lib: Fatal error. Command htlatex returned exit code 1
>
```

Where `filter.lua` is

```
local filter = require "make4ht-filter"

local function process_options(options)
  -- convert [number={foo}] to \tag{foo}
  local number = options:match("number%s*=%s*{?(%w+)")
  if number then
    return "\\tag{" .. number .. "}"
  end
  return ""
end


local function escape_equal(str)
  -- there can be multiple equal characters in the string. we should put the & character
  -- just before the one which is not inside any group
  -- escape nested equal signs
  str = str:gsub("({[^{^}]+)=([^{^}]+})", "%1:EQUAL:%2")
  -- replace remaining =
  str = str:gsub("=", "& =")
  -- return escaped =
  str = str:gsub(":EQUAL:", "=")
  return str
end

local function make_align(dgroup, new_env)
  -- change breqn environment contents to align*
  -- change = to &=
  -- local dgroup = escape_equal(dgroup) <- we don't do this anymore, it leads only to problems
  local new_env = new_env or  "\\begin{align*}\n%s\n\\end{align*}"
  -- return the fixed text in align* environment
  -- return "\\begin{".. new_env .."}" ..  dgroup .. "\\end{" .. new_env .. "}"
  return string.format(new_env, dgroup)
end

local function process_dgroup(s, env_name)
  return s:gsub("\\begin%s*{" .. env_name .. "}(.-)\\end%s*{" .. env_name .. "}",
  function(dgroup)
    -- remove environemnts
    -- change dmath[...,number={label}] to \tag{label}
    dgroup = dgroup:gsub("\\begin%s*{dmath}%s*(%b[])", process_options)
    -- remove all other environemnts
    dgroup = dgroup:gsub("\\begin%s*{.-}","")
    dgroup = dgroup:gsub("\\end%s*{.-}", "\\\\")
    return make_align(dgroup)
  end)
end

-- process remaining dmath environments
local function process_dmath(s, env_name, new_env)
  return s:gsub("\\begin%s*{" .. env_name .. "}(.-)\\end%s*{" .. env_name .. "}",
  function(dmath)
    -- options can be still here
    local dmath = dmath:gsub("^%s*(%b[])", process_options)
    return make_align(dmath, new_env)
  end)
end

local process = filter {
  -- find all dgroup* environments and convert them to align*
  function(s)
    local s = process_dgroup(s,"dgroup%*")
    s = process_dgroup(s, "dgroup")
    -- process remaining dmath environments in the document
    s = process_dmath(s, "dmath%*", "\\[\n%s\n\\]")
    s = process_dmath(s, "dmath", "\\begin{equation}\n%s\n \\end{equation}")
    return s
  end
}

-- install filter to match HTML files
Make:match("html?$", process)
```

I made sure I have no other filter installed in my ~/.config/ folder which is loaded by default.

Question is: Does one needs to use mathjax config file and `mathjax` option, for the above filter to use to allow dmath to work in tex4ht? If not, then why this error? Do I need special .cfg for it to work?

I tried to edit texmf.cnf to increases some values hoping to get rid of this error, but nothing worked. Here is my current TL 2022 texmf.cnf

```
>cat /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf.cnf
buf_size=9000000
pool_size=9000000
main_memory=8000000
save_size=1000000
max_strings = 5000000
strings_free = 1000000
hash_extra=10000000
stack_size=500000
>
```

The following zip file contains all files.

[dmath_without_mathjax.zip](https://12000.org/tmp/04342022/dmath_without_mathjax.zip)

[image]

Could someone please try the above and see if they get same error? May be something wrong with my installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Breqn package isn't supported by TeX4ht yet. The build file with Lua filter cannot work outside of the MathJax mode, because the original LaTeX code is not kept in the HTML code.

I've created a simple version of `breqn.4ht`, which seems to support the basic functions without errors:

```
\renewenvironment{dmath*}[1][]{\[}{\]}
\renewenvironment{dmath}[1][]{\begin{equation}}{\end{equation}}
\renewenvironment{dsuspend}{}{\par}

% enumerate equation for \begin{dseries}
\def\@dseries[#1]{%
  \if\eq@hasNumber%
    \refstepcounter{equation}%
  \fi
  \begingroup%
   \a:equation%
   \ignorespaces%
}


% mimic the equatio environment
\def\end@dseries{%
  \b:equation 
  \if\eq@hasNumber%
  (\arabic{equation})%
  \fi%
\c:equation%
}


% this macro prints spurious equation number to the document, so we just reset it
\def\grp@finish{%
  \setbox\GRP@wholebox\vbox{%
    \let\breqn@elt\eqgrp@elt
    \the\GRP@queue
  }%
  \unvbox\GRP@wholebox
}


\def\eq@nulldisplay{%
  \xdef\EQ@displayinfo{%
    \relax}%
}

%% commands 
% fix wrong handling of fonts in \condition
\newcommand\:condition@a[2][\conditionpunct]{%
  \unpenalty\unskip\unpenalty\unskip % BRM Added
  \mbox{#1}%
  \hskip\conditionsep
  \ \if@tempswa\mbox{#2}\else\mbox{$\textmath@setup #2$}\fi
  \endgroup
}

\HLet\condition@a\:condition@a

\Hinput{breqn}
\endinput
```

It works with the following non-MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}%ext
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}      

\begin{dmath*}
y(x) = x^{2}+x +3
\end{dmath*}

\begin{dmath}
y(x) = x^{2}+x +3
\end{dmath}

\begin{dseries}
\begin{math}A\end{math},
\begin{math}B\end{math},
and
\begin{math}C\end{math}.
\end{dseries}

\begin{dmath}
y(x) = x^{2}+x +3
\end{dmath}

\begin{dseries*}
\begin{math}A\end{math},
\begin{math}B\end{math},
and
\begin{math}C\end{math}.
\end{dseries*}

\begin{dgroup}
\begin{dmath}
f(x)=\frac{1}{x} \condition{for $x\neq 0$}
\end{dmath}


\begin{dmath}
  T(n) \hiderel{\leq} T(2^n) \leq c(3^n - 2^n)
\end{dmath}
\end{dgroup}

\begin{dgroup*}
\begin{dmath}
f(x)=\frac{1}{x} \condition{for $x\neq 0$}
\end{dmath}


\begin{dmath}
  T(n) \hiderel{\leq} T(2^n) \leq c(3^n - 2^n)
\end{dmath}
\end{dgroup*}

\begin{dgroup*}[frame={0.4pt},framesep=0pt,compact]
  \begin{dmath*}
    (x+\cdots+y+\cdots + z) - (x+\cdots +2) = 0
  \end{dmath*}
  \begin{dsuspend}
    and
  \end{dsuspend}
  \begin{dmath*}[frame={0pt}]
    a=0
  \end{dmath*}
\end{dgroup*}

\end{document}
```

This is the result with pictorial equations:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Michal. But I am still getting same errors. May be I am not using it correctly. It will help if you could please explain where to put the .4ht file, and if your original filter is still needed? This is what I did. I put `breqn.4ht` you show above in my TEXMFMHOME path, along with where all the additional style files go. So far so good? Or do I need to put it somewhere? Then I used the command `make4ht  -ulm default -a debug -e filter.lua   index.tex "htm"` where `filter.lua` is your original filter...

Comment: ...This gives same error. Then I tried without `-e filter.lua`, this also gave an error. I also did `texconfig rehash` but had no effect. What is the correct way to set this new .4ht you show correctly? Thanks.

Comment: I also now tried putting your breqn.4ht in `/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/breqn.4ht`  instead. This also gave same error about tex running out of capacity. Did `texconfig rehash`, Tried with and without `-e filter.lua`. I do not know what Am I doing wrong.

Comment: @Nasser for start, just put it to the directory with your TeX file, that should find it always.

Comment: I just did. Same error, Could you please show the command you used? Do I still need to use `-e filter.lua`? I tried both cases. There seems to be something wrong with my setup but I have no idea what. I've put everything in this zip file again https://12000.org/tmp/04342022/dmath_without_mathjax.zip  could you please try it again?  Used same command I show above. TL 2022. If you think I need to reinstall TL 2022 I will do that.

Comment: @Nasser it seems that you didn't copy the whole `breqn.4ht` from my answer, it is missing macros from the beginning. I get the fatal error with your file too.

Comment: Opps, you are right. It was a copy error. I blame the mouse for this :) (this is why I prefer to put things in zip files, less chance of these types of errors). now it works. Actually it works without `filter.lua`. Does this mean your `filter.lua` is not needed any more? Even if I use mathjax? or do I need  `filter.lua` when using mathjax mode only? Thanks again.

Comment: @Nasser you need `filter.lua` only in the mathajax mode, as it translates `dmath` to something what MathJax understands.